# Diferença entre ligar tabelas com WHERE e com INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Estava aprendendo SQL e me deparei com as seguintes instruções:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Livros.Nome_Livro, tbl_Livros.ISBN_Livro, tbl_Autores.Nome_Autor
FROM 
    tbl_Livros, tbl_Autores
WHERE 
    tbl_Livros.AutorID_Livro = tbl_Autores.ID_Autor;
```

E a outra:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Livros.Nome_Livro, tbl_Livros.ISBN_Livro, tbl_Autores.Nome_Autor
FROM 
    tbl_Livros
INNER JOIN tbl_Autores ON tbl_Livros.AutorID_Livro = tbl_Autores.ID_Autor;
```

Os 2 comandos me retornaram os mesmo registros, gostaria de saber qual diferença entre eles. A diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN eu conheço, mas a diferença entre INNER JOIN e ligação usando WHERE eu não conheço.

Obrigado.

Comment: Where é para filtrar a consuta e o innerjoin serve para ligar chaves em 2 ou mais tabelas. Oinnerjoin tras para vc uma consulta em duas tabelas sendo ligadas por uma primary key ou uma foreign key

Comment: Se o otimizador de consultas estiver fazendo o seu trabalho certo, não deve haver diferença entre essas consultas. Elas são apenas duas maneiras de especificar o mesmo resultado desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo visual do meu cometario:

Supondo que temos duas tabela com relação de 1 para 1
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe o comportamento de filtro do `WHERE` nas duas consultas e na 2ª Consulta observe o o `INNER JOIN`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo o `INNER JOIN` - Retorna linha quando houver pelo menos uma correspondência em ambas as tabelas.

Comment: `Resumindo o INNER JOIN - Retorna linha quando houver pelo menos uma correspondência em ambas as tabelas.` e o `where` também. Conforme eu disse: Se o otimizador de consultas estiver fazendo o seu trabalho certo, não deve haver diferença entre essas consultas. Elas são apenas duas maneiras de especificar o mesmo resultado desejado.